# Wireless card finding

Tags: wireless, macbook, programming

I need to find out what wifi card my computers running while using Ubuntu and not my original OS, how can I do that? Brand new Linux user I just installed it

Comment: Your computer is using the same wireless card no matter what OS you are using. Can you make the question more clear?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the wireless card details from the command line. Please open a terminal `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`t` and run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

That funny pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the command below. It will display some information about all installed networking-related devices.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Agreed.